# Foreach loop through an array vs foreach loop through a csv Newbie assitance

Tags: arrays, powershell

Total powershell newb here

I have the below code - but when i run the data to an array as opposed to a csv i dont get the intended result - i believe when the command runs it tries to provide the whole array rather than each line.

```
Write-Host Please wait whilst Data is collected ... This may take a while ........   -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Green
# Get-UnifiedGroup -ResultSize Unlimited |?{$_.GroupSku -eq "Yammer"} |  Export-Csv "C:\Temp\yammerGroup.csv" -NoTypeInformation

[array]$Yammer = Get-UnifiedGroup -ResultSize Unlimited |?{$_.GroupSku -eq "Yammer"}  

$yammer | ForEach-Object {
#Import-CSV "C:\Temp\yammerGroup.csv" | ForEach-Object {

Write-Host *** Task 1 ***    Setting Group Hidden From Address List Attribute -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Green
#Set-UnifiedGroup -Identity $Yammer.id -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled $true #}

Write-Host *** Task Custom ***    Setting Custom Attribute -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Green
Set-UnifiedGroup -Identity $Yammer.id -customattribute1 test  

Write-Host *** Task 3 ***    Appending -Yammer To Group Name -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Green
#if (! ($Yammer.DisplayName.ToLower().EndsWith("-yammer") ) )
   # {
       # Set-UnifiedGroup -Identity $Yammer.id -DisplayName ($Yammer.DisplayName + "-Yammer")

  #  }
}
Write-Host Process is now Complete -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Green
```

When i unmask the csv lines and mask the array line the rest of the script works as expected and runs through each line in the csv and does the intended change to the group properties.

But if i try to run it to an array i get the below error on the changes

```
Set-UnifiedGroup -Identity $Yammer.id -customattribute1 test  
Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert the "System.Collections.ArrayList" value of type "System.Collections.ArrayList" to 
type "Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.UnifiedGroupIdParameter".
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-UnifiedGroup], ParameterBindin...mationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Set-UnifiedGroup
    + PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com
```

I must have the foreach loop wrong but i cant see how as it works with the csv.

Any pointers in the right direction ?

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of ```Set-UnifiedGroup -Identity $Yammer.id …``` you want ```Set-UnifiedGroup -Identity $_.id …```. The first creates an array of the ids of *all* items, unless there’s only one, when it evaluates to a single item (aka “member-access enumeration” - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration?view=powershell-7.2). The latter gets the id of the loop variable (aka the “context variable” - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#_)

Answer (score 0):

You are making a few mistakes in your code. When you pipe with Foreach-Object, you basically send every item through which will be referred to in the codeblock as '$_'.

So what you are doing here is (if the hashtag is removed):

```
$yammer | ForEach-Object {
#Import-CSV "C:\Temp\yammerGroup.csv" | ForEach-Object {
```

Foreach group in $yammer, import the CSV and then foreach item in the CSV hide the group with id $yammer.id ($yammer.id contains an array of all found groups and there respective id's).

So what concept should you use?

For instance looping through the found groups and hide them from addresslist:

```
$Yammer = Get-UnifiedGroup -ResultSize Unlimited |?{$_.GroupSku -eq "Yammer"}  
$yammer | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host *** Task 1 ***    Setting Group Hidden From Address List Attribute -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Green
    Set-UnifiedGroup -Identity $_.id -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled $true
}
```

Or use the CSV instead:

```
Get-UnifiedGroup -ResultSize Unlimited |?{$_.GroupSku -eq "Yammer"} |  Export-Csv "C:\Temp\yammerGroup.csv" -NoTypeInformation
Import-CSV "C:\Temp\yammerGroup.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host *** Task 1 ***    Setting Group Hidden From Address List Attribute -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Green
    Set-UnifiedGroup -Identity $_.id -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled $true
}
```